# Problems with referencing and calling methods in another class

Tags: java, object, methods, reference, instance-variables

I am unsure how to go about setting up a method in a golf Player class. This class calls on other methods of another class called ScoreCard so I will include that class here as well.
Player class:

```
    public class Player
    {
        private String name;
        private ScoreCard card;
        private int longestDrive;
        private int fullDriveYards;
        private int fullDrives;
        private int drivesOnTarget;

    public Player(String PlayerName)
    {
        if (PlayerName == null)
        {
            this.name = "Unknown";
        }
        else
        {
            this.name = PlayerName;
        }
    }
    this.card = new ScoreCard;
    this.longestDrive = 0;
    this.fullDriveYards = 0;
    this.fullDrives = 0;
    this.drivesOnTarget = 0;
    }

    // This is the method I need help on
    public void recordPlayer(int hole, int strokes, int driveYds, String    location)
    {
    // make sure the hole number is  valid
    this.card  = new ScoreCard();
    card.getHolesPlayed();
    if (true)
    {
        // replace condition below with a test for valid hole
        // I will list the conditions in a second after I am done showing     the classes
        // record player's score on this hole
        card.getTotalStrokes();
        // use this.card and call on a ScoreCard method
        this.card.recordScore(0, 0);
        // define the conditions under which values of each of the int-type
        // variables are adjusted and the new values they will have

        }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public int getLongestDrive()
    {
        return this.longestDrive;
    }

    public int getFullDrives()
    {
        return this.fullDrives;
    }

    public int fullDriveYds()
    {
        return this.fullDriveYards;
    }

    public double computeFullAvg()
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    public int getDrivesOnTarget()
    {
        return this.drivesOnTarget;
    }

    public double computeAccuracy()
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String playerReport = this.card.toString();

        // add their driving statitics
        playerReport = playerReport + "\nLongest Full Drive: " + 
            this.getLongestDrive();
        playerReport = playerReport + "\nAverage Full Drive: " + 
            this.computeFullAvg();
        playerReport = playerReport + "\nDriving Accuracy: " + 
            this.computeAccuracy();
    }
}
```

Here is the ScoreCard Class:

```
    public class ScoreCard
    {
        private int totalStrokes;
        private int versusPar;
        private LinkedList<Integer> playerScoreCard;

    public ScoreCard()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        totalStrokes = 0;
        versusPar = 0;
        playerScoreCard = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    public void recordScore(int inHole, int inStrokes)
    {
        // put your code here
        if ((inHole >= 1) && (inHole <= playerScoreCard.size() + 1)) {
            playerScoreCard.add(inHole - 1, inStrokes);
        }
        totalStrokes += inStrokes;
        versusPar += (inStrokes - Course.getHole(inHole).getPar());
    }

    public int getHolesPlayed()
    {
        return playerScoreCard.size();
    }

     public int getTotalStrokes()
    {
        return totalStrokes;
    }

    public int getVersusPar()
    {
        return versusPar;
    }

public String toString()
    {
        return "Holes Played: " + getHolesPlayed() + "\n" +
                "Total Strokes: " + getTotalStrokes() + "\n" +
                "Versus Par: " + getVersusPar();
    }
}
```

Now here are the conditions for the Player class recordPlay method:
The recordPlay method calls on a method of the related ScoreCard instance to record the player's score on the hole. IT also adjusts the values of other instance variables using the following rules:

1. A drive is considered on target only if the recorded location is "Fairway" or "Green."
2. A drive counts as full drive if: a) it is recorded on a hole of sufficient length (any length that is 400 yards and greater and use the isFullDriveHole ) b) The drive location is on target.
3. Only full drives are considered for being the longest drive

I am done with mostly everything except the recordPlay method it's really giving me some trouble

Comment: "really giving me some trouble" What trouble, precisely?

Comment: I am unsure how to defne the conditions